# Laravel 'Illegal string offset 'leave_form' issue with array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I have an edit page where I display the data from a leave application form. I get an error 'Illegal string offset 'leave_form' when I update my form. I am using Vue.js and PHP. I manage to get the other data saved, that is in the leaveData object. When I try to save in the dateFrom in array of objects. leaveData['leave_form'] then I get the error. I suspect the problem lies in my foreach statement under the controller.

My array (just an example that I copied and pasted from console so you can see the object keys and values):

```
leaveData = [
alternativeName: "testos",
applicantSignature:"1",
applicantSignedDate:"2017-12-12",
contactDetailDuringLeave:"999999",
created_at:"2017-12-12 08:05:44",
created_by:6,
id:21,

leave_form = [
conditionsOfPay:"test",
created_at:"2017-12-12 08:05:44",
dateFrom:"2017-12-12",
dateTo:"2017-12-15",
id:15,
leave_application_id:21,
name:"Vacation Leave",
numberOfDays:2,
]
]
```

Here is a part of my blade HTML(just the leave_form part):

```
             <tbody>
                <tr v-for="leave in leaveData.leave_form">
                  <th scope="row">@{{ leave.name }}</th>
                  <td><input  v-pikaday="leave.dateFrom" class="form-control" v-model="leave.dateFrom" type="text"/></td>
                  <td><input v-pikaday="leave.dateTo" class="form-control"  v-model="leave.dateTo" type="text"/></td>
                  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="numberOfDays" v-model="leave.numberOfDays"></td>
                  <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="conditionsOfPay" v-model="leave.conditionsOfPay"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```

Here is my Vue.js:

```
   var leaveApply = new Vue({
el: '#leaveCreate',
data: {
  leaveData: <?php echo $leaveApplication ?>,
  getUserData: <?php echo $users ?>,
},

methods: {

  submitForm: function(){
      var that = this;

      var value = that.leaveData;

      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $("#_token").attr("content")
          }
      });

      $.ajax({
      url: '/admin/internal/leave/update/' + value.id,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
          leaveData: that.leaveData,
          personnelNumber: that.leaveData.personnelNumber,
          user_id: that.leaveData.user_id,
          alternativeName: that.leaveData.alternativeName,
          contactDetailDuringLeave: that.leaveData.contactDetailDuringLeave,
          applicantSignature: that.leaveData.applicantSignature,
          applicantSignedDate: that.leaveData.applicantSignedDate,
          managerApproval: that.leaveData.managerApproval,
          managerSignedDate: that.leaveData.managerSignedDate,
      },
      success: function(response) {
         toastr.success('Leave Application Updated');
      },
      error: function(error){
        toastr.error('Something went wrong');
      }
  });
   },
 },
   });
```

My Controller:

```
   public function update (Request $request, $id){

  $leaveApplication = LeaveApplication::with('user','leaveDept','leaveForm', 'leaveTask')->find($id);
  $leaveApplication->personnelNumber = $request->input('personnelNumber');
  $leaveApplication->alternativeName = $request->input('alternativeName');
  $leaveApplication->contactDetailDuringLeave = $request->input('contactDetailDuringLeave');
  $leaveApplication->managerApproval = filter_var($request->input('managerApproval'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
  $leaveApplication->applicantSignature = filter_var($request->input('applicantSignature'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
  $leaveApplication->applicantSignedDate = $request->input('applicantSignedDate');
  $leaveApplication->managerSignedDate = $request->input('managerSignedDate');

  foreach($request->input('leaveData') as $leaveData){
    $leaveApplication->dateFrom = $leaveData['leave_form']['dateFrom'];
    $leaveApplication->update();
  }

  $leaveApplication->update();

  return response()->json($leaveApplication);
}
```

Comment: `leave_form:[]` is not a valid php syntax. The error is coming from php also

Comment: Edited it - I copied and pasted from the console and just edited it so you can have an idea of what the array looks like

Answer (score 0):

```
$leaveApplication = LeaveApplication::with('user','leaveDept','leaveForm', 'leaveTask')->find($id);

$leaveApplication->dateFrom = $leaveData['leave_form']['dateFrom'];
```

You have leave_form and LeaveForm. Maybe the problem is here.  Also this code

```
 foreach($request->input('leaveData') as $leaveData){
    $leaveApplication->dateFrom = $leaveData['leave_form']['dateFrom'];
    $leaveApplication->update();
  }
```

repeats the process and saves the last foreach value into your record.

It also means that you are calling update 2 times.